# Test-jar in Classpath during Test SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

We have a Stub classes and Real classes of disptach-reboot in two seperate jars. We need a way in SBT so that we need Stub classes in class path when unit test is run and Real classes when code running in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [multi-project .sbt build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html#Three+Flavors+of+Build+Definition) and [unmanaged dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies):

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  dependencyClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "lib-main" / "realclasses.jar",
  dependencyClasspath in Runtime += baseDirectory.value / "lib-main" / "realclasses.jar",
  dependencyClasspath in Test    += baseDirectory.value / "lib-test" / "stubclasses.jar"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(commonSettings: _*)
```